# Python replace nested for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

t = np.random.rand(3,3,3) 

def foo(T):    

    res = np.zeros((3,3,3))
    
    for a in range(3):
        for b in range(3):
            for c in range(3):
                idx = [a,b,c]
                combinations = list(itertools.permutations(idx, len(idx)))
                idx_arrays = tuple(np.array(idx) for idx in zip(*combinations))     
                res[a, b, c] = (1.0/len(combinations))*np.sum(T[idx_arrays])
        
        
    return res

sol = foo(t)
```

The code above should be the equivalent to doing:

```
for a in range(3):
        for b in range(3):
            for c in range(3):
                res2[a,b,c] = (1.0/6)*(
                                        t[a,b,c]
                                        + t[a,c,b]
                                        + t[b,a,c]
                                        + t[b,c,a]
                                        + t[c, a, b]
                                        + t[c,b,a]
                                        )
```

To make the code faster, I would like to replace the outer `for loops`. Can this be done? Ideally this should be achieved without using `einsum` method of numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You can start improving by not doing duplicated computations:

```py
def foo(t):
    res = np.zeros_like(t).astype(t.dtype)
    A, B, C = t.shape
    for a in range(A):
        for b in range(a, B):
            for c in range(b, C):
                r = (1.0 / 6) * (
                    t[a, b, c]
                    + t[a, c, b]
                    + t[b, a, c]
                    + t[b, c, a]
                    + t[c, a, b]
                    + t[c, b, a]
                )
                res[a, b, c] = r
                res[a, c, b] = r
                res[b, a, c] = r
                res[b, c, a] = r
                res[c, a, b] = r
                res[c, b, a] = r
    return res
```

Comment: This a good solution. But for higher dimensions of `t` the unfolding as is will be problematic

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner, using `np.transpose` to vectorize:

```
np.stack([t.transpose(i) for i in itertools.permutations(np.arange(3), 3)]).mean(0)
```

Those `3`s can be changed or functionalized if you want higher dimensionality than 3

import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations as perm

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations as perm

def foo(T):
    dims = len(T.shape)
    assert np.all(np.array(T.shape) == T.shape[0])
    all_perms = np.stack([T.transpose(i) for i in perm(np.arange(dims), dims)])
    return all_perms.mean(0)
```

Comment: This is very nice. I can go to `4` and `5` with this one! However, if does not give exactly 0 when I subtract this code from mine. Is it the order of summation?

Comment: Likely it's just floating point errors.  Try using `np.allclose()` to check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is faster than 3 nested for loops. Anyways you can try this:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

t = np.random.rand(3,3,3)

def foo(T):    
    t = np.random.rand(3,3,3) 
    res = np.zeros((3,3,3))
    
    for a, b, c in set(itertools.permutations((0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 3)):
        idx = [a,b,c]
        combinations = list(itertools.permutations(idx, len(idx)))
        idx_arrays = tuple(np.array(idx) for idx in zip(*combinations))     
        res[a, b, c] = (1.0/len(combinations))*np.sum(t[idx_arrays])
        
        
    return res

sol = foo(t)
```

Here, instead of using `3 nested for loops` I am creating `unique permutations` of `3 elements` from the tuple `(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)`.

Comment: Timing wise, it unfortunately seems that this solution is actually very slightly slower than the OPs original function (I'm not sure why). This times at 186 µs versus 178 µs for the original function (on my laptop).

Comment: You could make it a bit faster by using `product` instead of `permutations`, e.g., replace `set(itertools.permutations((0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 3))` with `itertools.product(range(3), repeat=3)`

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
def foo2(T):
    indices = np.indices((3, 3, 3)).reshape(3, -1)
    all_permutations = np.array(list(itertools.permutations(indices, len(indices))))
    idx_arrays = tuple(np.array(idx) for idx in zip(*all_permutations))
    summed = np.sum(T[tuple(idx_arrays)], axis=0)
    res = (1.0 / len(all_permutations)) * summed
    return res.reshape(3, 3, 3)
```

In short, you reshape the output of `np.indices` to generate the idx_arrays. Then you sum the values from the original array using advanced indexing and divide by the number of permutations. Finally, reshape the result back to a 3x3x3 array.

This code produces the same results as the original one but in a more efficient manner by leveraging the power of NumPy's vectorized operations.

On my machine:

```
%%timeit foo(t)
%%timeit foo2(t)
261 µs ± 4.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
36.7 µs ± 296 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```